# Do exposure notification apps from different governments communicate?

Tags: notifications, developer-program

Do [exposure notification](https://www.macrumors.com/guide/exposure-notification/) apps developed by different governments communicate? The user experience for exposure notifications makes it seem like they are a platform feature, but what I've read on several government websites makes it seem like there is no sharing of information between apps from different states, so that, for example, I won't be notified of someone using another state's app exposes me.

Do exposure notification apps from different governments communicate?

Comment: Which apps and from which countries are you referring to?  In the US, different states can use their own apps or use frameworks provided by 3rd-parties like Apple an d Google.  Throughtout the world, different governments can implement any sort of app they deem appropriate.

Comment: @fsb This is a question about apps that use the Apple/Google Exposure Notification API.

Comment: You should update your question with that info because the answer provided would be impacted by that.